# i want to know the purpose of the following c++ code

Tags: c++, pointers

i understand the code creates a pointer variable as a 2d array. but i feel like instead of
being used to store address of the another variable(2d array) the pointer variable is stored with the actual numbers so as to get away with the shortcomings of using just an array. 
am i right or wrong? help me improve my understanding of pointers.

```
double** assign_initial_guess(
    int nx,
    int ny,
    double top,
    double left,
    double right,
    double bottom,
    double interior)
{
    //n --> number of nodes in one direction
    //top,left,right,bottom,interior --> values need to assigned at respective nodes
    double** u=0;
    int ind=0;
    u=new double*[nx];

    for(int i=0;i<nx;i++)
    {
        u[ind]=new double[ny];
        for(int j=0;j<ny;j++)
        {
            u[i][j]=interior;
            if(i==0)
                { u[i][j]=top;} // top boundary

            if(j==0 && i>0 && i<(nx-1))
                { u[i][j]=left;} // left boundary

            if(j==(ny-1) && i>0 && i<(nx-1))
                { u[i][j]=right;} // right boundary

            if(i==(nx-1))
                { u[i][j]=bottom;} // bottom boundary
        }
        ind+=1;
    }
    return u;
}
```

Comment: Try to format your code a bit before posting, next time, as Whozcraig has done for you.

Comment: @citelao hopefully at-least readable now.

Comment: The usefulness of `ind` in this code is questionable to offer anything besides confusion. Walk the code and then consider its elimination, replacing it with `i`, and removing the `ind += 1` at the bottom entirely. Perhaps it will be a little clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what you really want to know, but:

Each **variable** (doesn't matter of what type), has it's own (sometimes shared with others, but lets skip that for a moment) place in your PC's memory. **Pointers** store information about the **address** of the memory in which a particular variable is at. The `new` operator in your code is used to assign some memory for a variable. The code your provided doest the following:

```
u=new double*[nx];
```

Allocates the memory needed to store `nx` pointers (so `nx*sizeof(double*)`) and gets the address of the allocated memory. The address is stored in the pointer `u`.

```
u[ind]=new double[ny];
```

Allocates the memoy needed to store `ny` doubles (so `ny*sizeof(double)`), and get the address of the allocated memory. The address is stored in the pointer `u[ind]`.

Answer (score -1):

pointers are references to other variables, and don't actually contain any values.

Comment: Pointers are NOT references. References are references. Pointers point to data, and they don't have to point to other variables.

Comment: This is wrong. A pointer is independent variable; they're not references, and *do* contain a value. (an address).